# Mysql query are case sensitive?

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

When i set lower_case_table_names = 1 in mysql i know that it converts every table name to lowecase so "myCoolLowerCaseName" becomes "mycoollowercasename". But the question is:
queries with camelcase name works ? with a table called mycoollowercasename the query:`SELECT * FROM myCoolLowerCaseName` works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, table names are sensitive. You need to use the case sensitive name of the table in your queries.